# how to get input html form in mule flow

Tags: mule

I have a mule application that contains a Choice component. I want to send a text parameter in HTML Form which will be tested in choice component to choose which branch will be executed. my question is how to have the value of this parameter in the mule Flow , what expression MEL to get the value of parameter posted .

thanks for yours supports

Answer (score 0):

If you send HTML form via GET, you can use this

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.your_input_name]
```

If you send it by POST, the payload is a ParameterMap. So, try this:

```
#[payload.get('your_input_name')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply  @Alexis Ochoa ,but  i used this expression it returned   "Null Payload".

Comment: Did you change the field name? For `<form ...><input type="text" name="field1">...</form>` you receive `#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.field1]` or `#[payload.get('field1')]`